# Match url with regex but leave specific string from match

Tags: regex

I want to match the following URL

`/root/folder/123`

without the `/root` in front of it. I was trying around with this pattern `((?!root).)*$` which I found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/237312

but it doesn't work either, because it still matches `oot/folder/123`. I thought about something like `(?!(root)+.)*$` which matches nothing, so I'm looking for an answer here.

Comment: Do you want to match the URL but return everything without `/root` or do you want to match URLs like this if they do **not** start wit `/root`?

Comment: I want to match URLs starting with `/root`in front, but I don't want to match it. Kev's asnwer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lookbehind`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) syntax: `(?<=...)`

For example:

```
(?<=/root).*$
```

It'll match `/folder/123`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
\/root(.+)
```

The first group, i.e., $1 will be /folder/123